# What to use instead of ResultSet when converting from SQL Server CE to SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite

I'm new to C# so excuse me if my question is unclear.

In my application a report can be created from an existing database recording lots of values. Before SQL Server CE was used and everything was working fine but now I'm working on changing it to SQLite.

So the problem is I don't know what kind of command to use instead of `ResultSet`. I tried using `DataReader` as you can see in my code below, but it doesn't work. Instead I get a message "An error occurred when trying to generate a report! SQL logic error or missing database no such table: Data1".
I inserted some `MessageBox.Show` with numbers to see where the problem seemed to be and the message box after this line is never executed:
`SQLiteDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader(ReaderOptions.Scrollable);`

If anyone knows how to do it it would be really helpful.

This is what the code used to look like with SQL Server CE:

```
namespace Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated
{

    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Graphics.Logic;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces;

    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;

    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

    using FlexCel.Core;
    using FlexCel.XlsAdapter;
    using FlexCel.Render;

    public partial class scmFlexCel
    {   
        public void CreateData1XLS(bool Silent)
        {
            try
            {
                string sFromSel = Silent ? Globals.Tags.ReportScheduleFrom.Value : Globals.Tags.ReportFrom.Value;
                string sToSel = Silent ? Globals.Tags.ReportScheduleTo.Value : Globals.Tags.ReportTo.Value;

                DateTime dFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(sFromSel);
                DateTime dTo = Convert.ToDateTime(sToSel);

                if(!Silent) 
                { 
                    if((dTo - dFrom).TotalDays > 10) //If not silent and a periode >10 days, show message box.
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The time period has to be maximum 10 days!","Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }                        
                } 


                string sFrom = dFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                string sTo = dTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                //Make sure that the path and template file name is correct
                string sRunPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName);
                string sProjFilesPath = sRunPath + @"\Project Files\";

                //Open the database 
                SqlCeConnection conn =  new SqlCeConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = "data source=" + sRunPath + @"\Database.sdf";
                conn.Open();

                //SQL question
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Data1 WHERE '" + sFrom + "' <= [Time] AND [Time] <= '" + sTo + "' AND NOT Long IS NULL ORDER BY [Time]";

                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql,conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlCeResultSet rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);


                if(rs.HasRows) //If rows exists
                {
                    FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile xls = new FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile(sProjFilesPath + "Data1.xls");

                    xls.ActiveSheet = 1; //Make sure we work with Sheet1

                    int iRow = 4; //Row in xls sheet where to start to insert data from sql

                    while(rs.Read())
                    {
                        DateTime dt = rs.GetDateTime(rs.GetOrdinal("Time")); xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 1, dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 2, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("Long")).TrimEnd()); //Longitude
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 3, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("Lat")).TrimEnd()); //Latitude
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 4, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("Loop")).TrimEnd());
                    //  xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 5, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("BleedOff_ZeroDis")).TrimEnd());
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 5, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("CEMSAnalyzer")).TrimEnd());
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 6, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("So2")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("So2")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 7, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("Co2")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("Co2")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 8, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("Ratio")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("Ratio")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 9, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("EngineLoad")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("EngineLoad")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 16, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempIn")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempIn")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 17, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempOut")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempOut")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 14, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterPressure")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterPressure")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 15, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterFlow")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterFlow")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 18, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresBefore")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresBefore")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 19, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresDrop")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresDrop")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 20, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempBefore")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempBefore")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 21, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempAfter")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempAfter")));
                        iRow++;
                    }

                    // Save XLS File with a SaveFileDialog.
                    SaveFileDialog savexls = new SaveFileDialog();
                    savexls.Filter = "xls files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
                    savexls.FilterIndex = 1 ;

                    // Set the properties on SaveFileDialog1 so the user is prompted to create the file if it doesn't exist or overwrite the file if it does exist. 
                    savexls.CreatePrompt = true;
                    savexls.OverwritePrompt = true;

                    // Set the file name to Data1_"DateTime".xls and set the initial directory to the MyComputer folder.
                    savexls.FileName = "Data1_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")+ ".xls";

                    savexls.InitialDirectory = 
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);

                    //Save the xls file Call ShowDialog and check for a return value of DialogResult.OK, which indicates that the file was saved. 
                    DialogResult result = savexls.ShowDialog();

                    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        string newDirectory = savexls.FileName;
                        xls.Save(newDirectory); //Save the xls file 
                        MessageBox.Show("File successfully saved!","Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                else //If rows not exist in the specified time frame, show message box.
                {
                    if(!Silent)
                        MessageBox.Show("There's no data for the specified period!","Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
                conn.Close(); //Close database connection   
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //If any error, show message box. 
            {
                //Maybe you want to activate an alarm tag instead of showing a MessageBox ?
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred when trying to generate a report!\n" + ex.Message,"Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my attempt to make it work in SQLite:

```
namespace Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated
{

    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Graphics.Logic;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces;

    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;

    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SQLite;

    using FlexCel.Core;
    using FlexCel.XlsAdapter;
    using FlexCel.Render;

    public partial class scmFlexCel
    {   
        public void CreateData1XLS(bool Silent)
        {
            try
            {
                string sFromSel = Silent ? Globals.Tags.ReportScheduleFrom.Value : Globals.Tags.ReportFrom.Value;
                string sToSel = Silent ? Globals.Tags.ReportScheduleTo.Value : Globals.Tags.ReportTo.Value;

                DateTime dFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(sFromSel);
                DateTime dTo = Convert.ToDateTime(sToSel);

                if(!Silent) 
                { 
                    if((dTo - dFrom).TotalDays > 10) //If not silent and a periode >10 days, show message box.
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The time period has to be maximum 10 days!","Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }                        
                } 


                string sFrom = dFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                string sTo = dTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                //Make sure that the path and template file name is correct
                string sRunPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName);
                string sProjFilesPath = sRunPath + @"\Project Files\";

                //Open the database 
                SQLiteConnection conn =  new SQLiteConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = "data source=" + sRunPath + @"\Database.sdf";
                conn.Open();

                //SQL question
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Data1 WHERE '" + sFrom + "' <= [Time] AND [Time] <= '" + sTo + "' AND NOT Long IS NULL ORDER BY [Time]";

                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql,conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SQLiteDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader(ReaderOptions.Scrollable);


                if(rs.HasRows) //If rows exists
                {
                    FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile xls = new FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile(sProjFilesPath + "Data1.xls");

                    xls.ActiveSheet = 1; //Make sure we work with Sheet1

                    int iRow = 4; //Row in xls sheet where to start to insert data from sql

                    while(rs.Read())
                    {
                        DateTime dt = rs.GetDateTime(rs.GetOrdinal("Time")); xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 1, dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 2, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("Long")).TrimEnd()); //Longitude
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 3, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("Lat")).TrimEnd()); //Latitude
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 4, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("Loop")).TrimEnd());
                    //  xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 5, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("BleedOff_ZeroDis")).TrimEnd());
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 5, rs.GetString(rs.GetOrdinal("CEMSAnalyzer")).TrimEnd());
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 6, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("So2")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("So2")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 7, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("Co2")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("Co2")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 8, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("Ratio")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("Ratio")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 9, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("EngineLoad")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("EngineLoad")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 16, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempIn")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempIn")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 17, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempOut")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterTempOut")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 14, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterPressure")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterPressure")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 15, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterFlow")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("WaterFlow")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 18, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresBefore")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresBefore")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 19, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresDrop")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasPresDrop")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 20, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempBefore")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempBefore")));
                        xls.SetCellValue(iRow, 21, rs.IsDBNull(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempAfter")) ? 0 : rs.GetFloat(rs.GetOrdinal("ExhGasTempAfter")));
                        iRow++;
                    }

                    // Save XLS File with a SaveFileDialog.
                    SaveFileDialog savexls = new SaveFileDialog();
                    savexls.Filter = "xls files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
                    savexls.FilterIndex = 1 ;

                    // Set the properties on SaveFileDialog1 so the user is prompted to create the file if it doesn't exist or overwrite the file if it does exist. 
                    savexls.CreatePrompt = true;
                    savexls.OverwritePrompt = true;

                    // Set the file name to Data1_"DateTime".xls and set the initial directory to the MyComputer folder.
                    savexls.FileName = "Data1_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")+ ".xls";

                    savexls.InitialDirectory = 
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);

                    //Save the xls file Call ShowDialog and check for a return value of DialogResult.OK, which indicates that the file was saved. 
                    DialogResult result = savexls.ShowDialog();

                    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        string newDirectory = savexls.FileName;
                        xls.Save(newDirectory); //Save the xls file 
                        MessageBox.Show("File successfully saved!","Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                else //If rows not exist in the specified time frame, show message box.
                {
                    if(!Silent)
                        MessageBox.Show("There's no data for the specified period!","Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
                conn.Close(); //Close database connection   
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //If any error, show message box. 
            {
                //Maybe you want to activate an alarm tag instead of showing a MessageBox ?
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred when trying to generate a report!\n" + ex.Message,"Report",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "but it does not work" --- you need to be more specific!

Comment: I get an error message: "An error occurred when trying to generate a report! SQL logic error or missing database no such table: Data1". I inserted some message boxes so I know it stops working at this line: SQLiteDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader(ReaderOptions.Scrollable);